# DeprecationWarning: json is deprecated al testear con Pytest

Tags: python, flask

Estoy testeando con Pytest 3.10 una aplicación montada sobre Flask 0.12.2 y Werkzeug 0.14.1. El testing funciona bien solo que al final, Pytest muestra el resumen de los warnings que se han ido detectando a lo largo del test:

```
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
tests/test_subdomain.py::TestSubsubdomain::()::test_post[test_input0-201 CREATED]
  <PATH_LIB_PROYECTO>/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py:347: DeprecationWarning: json is deprecated.  Use get_json() instead.
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
# mas warnings de este tipo...
```

Este es el warning que se repite constantemente debido a que cuando trato de probar un método de tipo POST, la aplicación me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
# Endpoint cualquiera de la aplicación

# `entity` es el objeto JSON insertado en la base 
# de datos junto con su identificador 
return flask.Response(
    jsonpickle.encode(entity,unpicklable=False),
    CREATED,
    mimetype='application/json'
)
```

La forma que tengo de parsear la respuesta en los tests es la siguiente:

```
import json

# más imports...    

class TestSubdomain(object):

    new_data = None

    # más tests de la clase...

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input, expected", input_test_post_data)
    def test_post(self, ste, domain_fxt, test_input, expected):
        """
            Post one or more subdomains
        """
        rsp = ste['test_client'].post(url, data=generate_subdomain_data(test_input, domain_fxt['domain_id']))
        assert rsp.status == expected
        TestSubsubdomain.new_data = json.dumps(rsp.data)
```

Recurro al módulo `json` propio de Python para transformar la respuesta a JSON ya que la clase `flask.Response` no dispone de un método de tipo `get_json()`, como sí la tiene la `flask.Request`. Por ello, no entiendo el motivo de los warnings generados por Pytest.

He visto este [issue de Flask](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1278) que parece tener el mismo problema que yo pero en mi caso se trata de una respuesta y no una petición, por tanto no me sirve de mucho.

¿El motivo del warning se encuentra en como la aplicación devuelve la respuesta?¿Es quizás cosa de como paso la respuesta a JSON en el test?

Muchas gracias

**Referencias**

[Flask.Response y Flask.Request](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12-maintenance/flask/wrappers.py)

[Warnings en Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html)

Comment: Yo creo que el warning no proviene de que hayas importado el módulo `json`, sino de que en algún momento intentas acceder al campo ` .json`  de un objeto (una `request` o una `response`). En el código que pegas no veo eso, pero tiene que estar en alguna otra parte de tu código. Lo que está _deprecated_ no es la biblioteca `json`, sino ese nombre de atributo dentro de los objetos Werkzeug (biblioteca usada internamente por Flask)

Comment: @abulafia Sin embargo, al hacer un `print(dir(rsp))` ni el atributo `.json` ni el método `.get_json()` figuran entre los atributos del objeto `rsp` por lo que entiendo que, si no está, al tratar de acceder a ese supuesto campo debería lanzar una excepción y no un warning que me recomiende emplear un método o atributo que no existe, ¿no?

Comment: No creas. Python permite tener atributos "dinamicos", gracias a que todo objeto tiene un método `__getattribute__()`, que es llamado cuando el atributo no se encuentra directamente. Ahi dentro ya se puede hacer lo que quieras, y por tanto "emular" otros atributos aparentemente inexistentes. Y también desde ahí se puede generar un _warning_, que es lo que werkzeug aparentemente está haciendo cuando se le pide `"json"` como atributo.

Comment: De todas formas, hay algo que no entiendo con lo de ese warning... Usas python 2.7, por lo que supongo que también estarás usando una versión de Flask/Werzeug más antigua que la mía, ya que yo uso python 3.5. Y en mi versión ese DeprecationWarning no lo encuentro, y en cambio sí está definido un método `json()` con el decorador `@property`, que permite usarlo como si fuera un atributo (`r.json`) y simplemente llama a `get_json()`. Es decir, parece que esa "deprecation" ha sido revertida en versiones más recientes (?)

Comment: @abulafia Correcto, uso Python 2.7 y sí, en la versión actual de Flask, la clase `flask.Response` hereda de las clases `ResponseBase` y de `JSONMixin`. Esta última es la que le facilita el méodo `get_json` y el atributo `json`. Sin embargo, en la versión que estoy empleando yo, la 0.12, no lo tiene.